# CreateProcessAsUser under Local System Admin returns "5: acces denied"

Tags: c, windows, winapi, admin, sccm

I've been struggling to launch a process started under Local System Account (via remote deployment service) under another registered user account. I've followed these steps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And it works on my local XP-machine. I.e. my process is started from the registered user account and executes everything in the right context. But one of the users (also on XP) has issues, getting error code 5 after CreateProcessAsUser. I cannot reproduce this and am trying to investigate why this is happening.
 Interestingly I even removed the permissions to Read/Execute for my registered admin on a specific folder I've got my exe in, but it still runs everything, so I'm not quite sure where to look to find the source of the problem.
 I would appreciate any advice in which direction to look in order to resolve this. Maybe you've had similar experience and managed to find a way how to resolve this?

Thanks!

PS I'm simulating local system admin via psexec /si cmd

Comment: I think you've got the wrong link there.

Comment: Does the account have the appropriate logon right?  (Which logon right is needed depends on the flags you've passed to `LogonUser`.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks, fixed the link. As I mentioned it works fine on my machine when I'm under system account and the user can run the process when he's logged in under the target user account (i.e. the user has the right to execute this binary). So not exactly sure why access is denied.
BTW As a side note, the package is advertised through SCCM, so I wonder if there's something else I am not doing right to reproduce the environment.

Comment: I recommend adding diagnostic code that checks the security context in which `CreateProcessAsUser` is running.  In particular make sure that you have `SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME` and `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privileges; `CreateProcessAsUser` will fail with an access denied error if they aren't available.

Comment: Thanks Harry, in the end I followed the example completely + enabled all priviledges attached to the token. The error changed into a more meaningful message. It was actually a local security policy restriction, where unknown executables were not allowed to run.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.  Please post (and accept) an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I upvoted your comment but can't see a way to accept it as an answer. I.e. there's no checkbox to mark as answered.

Comment: You can post your own answer, and accept it - my suggestion may have helped, but it wasn't the actual answer!  Answering your own question is not only permitted on Stack Overflow, but encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end problem was to do with the local security policy restriction for Local System account + enabling all privileges on the token allowed to start the process.
As for SCCM, once I completely followed MSDN example and interactions were enabled on SCCM-package, things worked fine.